# my function() is not working or the value is not converting to a number

Tags: javascript, html, string, numbers

Been stuck here ALL day long trying to figure out what is wrong with my syntax.
Here’s my code… I’d like to verify if **Number1 is > than Number 2**. However, whenever I tried to run the code I always getting false.

Please help me..

PS. I am new to coding :(

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
var num2 = document.getElementById('num2');
 
var x = Number(num1);
var y = Number(num2);

function higherThan(x, y){
  x > y? alert(true) : alert(false);
}
```

```html
Numb1: <input type="number" id="num1"><br>
Numb2: <input type="" id="num2"><br>
<button onclick="higherThan();">Is Higher Than?</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('num1')` gets the whole element. Change it to `document.getElementById('num1').value` to get the value

Answer (score 0):

Get the values of the  inputs inside the function.In your case you are trying to get the value even before user have provided any input.
Also to get the value you need to do

```
document.getElementById('elemId').value
```

```js
function higherThan(x, y) {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;

  var x = Number(num1);
  var y = Number(num2);
  x > y ? alert(true) : alert(false);
}
```

```html
Numb1:
<input type="number" id="num1">
<br> Numb2:
<input type="" id="num2">
<br>
<button onclick="higherThan();"> Is Higher Than ?</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

a few things:

- you are not passing anything to your `higherThan()` function when you call it, but you have defined `higherThan()` as requiring two arguments.
- I'm not convinced you that `num1` and `num2` are actually numbers. I would use some console logs to verify that you are a.) getting something back here and b.) that what you are getting back is a number not a string. You may need to use `parseInt` as obviously you can't math with strings.
- What is happening here? `var x = Number(num1);` the way this is written it looks like you are calling a function? where is this function defined?
- I would test your code in jsfiddle or browser console first and verify it works before trying to embed it in a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the `value` from the control. You can pass the `id`'s of the control's to refer that inside the function for getting the values. Try the following way:

```js
function higherThan(n1, n2){
  var x = Number(document.getElementById(n1).value);
  var y = Number(document.getElementById(n2).value);
  var res = x > y? true : false;
  alert(res);
}
```

```html
Numb1: <input type="number" id="num1"><br>
Numb2: <input type="" id="num2"><br>
<button onclick="higherThan('num1','num2');">Is Higher Than?</button>
```

Comment: I followed your codes above and it is working now.. except that your declared variables x and y has the getElementById of X and Y.  should it be the two id of two texts? but thank you so much for the help. will keep these in mind.                  var x = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value);
var y = Number(document.getElementById('num2').value);